# Add UserControl to Canvas dynamically without invoking OnRender unnecessarily

Tags: c#, wpf

What’s the right way to add `UserControl`s to the `Canvas` dynamically? I need to add very many items, and I want `OnRender` invoked only as needed (when the `UserControl` is on the screen).

Right now, `OnRender` is called when creating/adding a `UserControl` to the `Canvas`, and I don’t like that because it uses extra resources.

```
// Main Window Code
int y = 0;

foreach(MyData d in data)
{
    // allocate control
    MyControl ctrl = new MyControl();
    // initialize properties
    ctrl.Name = d.Name;
    ctrl.Phone = d.Phone;
    // add control to canvas
    canvas.Children.Add(ctrl);
    // setup position
    Canvas.SetLeft(ctrl, 0);
    Canvas.SetTop(ctrl, y);
    y += Height;
}


// UserControl (MyControl) code
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    // custom draw code for Name & Phone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple boolean flag:

```
//Main Window Code
bool canRender = false;
int y=0;
foreach(MyData d in data)
{
  //allocate control
  MyControl ctrl=new MyControl();
  //initialize properties
  ctrl.Name=d.Name;
  ctrl.Phone=d.Phone;
  //add control to canvas
  canvas.Children.Add(ctrl);
  //setup position
  Canvas.SetLeft(ctrl, 0);
  Canvas.SetTop(ctrl, y);
  y+=Height;
}
canRender = true;
InvalidateVisual();


//UserControl code
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
   if(!canRender)
      return;
}
```

Comment: I wrote about OnRender for UserControl, and not for Window

Comment: There is no difference. You can add `canRender` to your control and then set it from the main window. `ctrl.CanRender = true`

Comment: I need to OnRender called only for objects which are now on the screen.